# Using facebook api login securely

Tags: authentication, facebook, token

I'm currently working on web application projects that utilise Json web token for the purpose of token authentication through a stateless server.
The process that which the system go about before giving a token is something like

1. User key in username and password
2. Back end server checks username and password against database
3. server returns with a JWT if authentication check succeeds

However, this process would not work for social app login like facebook as there would be no username or password for me to verify them with. I thought of using facebook access tokens to verify them but how should i actually go about doing it?

Comment: Are you asking how to use Facebook's API to verify their tokens?

Comment: Yes, i assume thats possible right?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Answer (score 1):

You need to [register](https://developers.facebook.com/) for a Facebook API key. Then you can begin using the OAuth service to authenticate users.

To answer your question, you can cut out the authentication piece of you application logic (that's what OAuth does for you). Once you have the assertion from OAuth you can use that to generate the JWT for the client.

Comment: i am actually using an oauth implementation to handle all my non facebook  logins which upon authentication would return them with a JWT. However for the facebook login, do you mean that i have to use their OAuth service which i assume would be given to me when i access facebook's authentication endpoint?

Comment: Correct, you would use FB's OAuth and handle the returned token the same way as the ones you create